# Upload Workout Parameters to Strava - Swift

Tags: swift, oauth, strava

I'm trying to upload my workout via my app to strava & when I send my request It return me with error 400 and this:

> (String?) $R0 = "{\"message\":\"Bad Request\",\"errors\":[{\"resource\":\"Upload\",\"field\":\"file\",\"code\":\"not a file\"}]}"

I was able to connect my app to strava without problem.
Here's what I've done so far:

```
func saveWorkout(_ workout: FirebaseWorkout, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    let opts: [String: Any?] = [
        "file": nil,
        "name": workout.name
        "description": nil,
        "trainer": false,
        "commute": false,
        "dataType": ".gpx",
        "externalId": workout.key
    ]
    if self.isAuthorized && userSettings.membership.hasFullAccess {
        workoutLib().analyticsEvent(kEventCategoryThirdParty, eventAction: "SAVE_WORKOUT", eventLabel: ThirdPartyApplication.strava.rawValue, eventValue: 1)
        workoutLib().debugLog("Strava: Save Workout")
        self.refreshTokenIfNeeded {
            _ = self.oauthswift.client.post("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads", parameters: opts as OAuthSwift.Parameters, success: { (_) in
                workoutLib().debugLog("Strava: Save Workout Success")
                completion(true, nil)
            }) { (error) in
                workoutLib().debugLog("Strava: Save Workout \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false, error)
            }
        }
    } else {
        completion(false, nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Strava API documentation (https://developers.strava.com/docs/uploads/), the `file` field is required and it looks like you've set it as `nil`. That's probably why it's returning `not a file` because there is no file passing through.